# change value of xml node with simpleXML

Tags: php, xml

I have this xml example

```
<items>
 <item>
    <id>k1</id>
    <price>456</price>
 </item>
 <item>
    <id>k2</id>
    <price>609</price>
 </item>
</items>
```

php code

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file(address of xml file);
     foreach ($xml->item as $item){
                 if($item->id == 'k2') {
                    item->price = 800;
             }
     }
```

if i want to change the value of second item with simpleXML how can i do that?I know that i can read and save the value to a variable with this $val=item->price; but if i want to change the value with this simple code item->price = 800; it's not working.why happens that?It's a simple thing but still difficult.. Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to update the XML? If so, this will not work. You'll have to export as XML again.

Comment: i just want to change the price 609 to 800. thanks

Comment: @user3071235 You need to export the XML string via [`SimpleXML::asXML()`](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.asxml.php)

Comment: `item->price` is a syntax error... did you mean `$item->price`?

Comment: yes..sorry i mean $item->price

Answer (score 0):

Use `xpath` to select the `<item>` you want and update it:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($x); // assume XML in $x

$result = $xml->xpath("/items/item[id = 'k2']");
$result[0]->price = 800;

echo $xml->asXML();
```

see it working: https://eval.in/88021

Comment: Thanks for your reply..but i have another problem now and i can not see if this solution working for me.My problem is that in $x variable i want to load an xml file from my hard disk.If i use simplexml_load_file to load the xml file into $x then i have a warning when i use the simplexml_load_string($x); The warning says Entity: line 12: parser error : Start tag expected, '&lt;' not found.