# Custom PHP function for Wordpress WP All Import plugin

Tags: php, xml, wordpress

I'm having trouble with XML file importing in WP All import Wordpress plugin. I want to change values of numbers/IDs to their assigned names. In XML file there's a node called "safety" which contains IDs that are connected with another XML file containing the name of safety entry.

What I would like to achieve is [changing XML values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33614875/wp-all-imports-php-function-editor-change-value-of-xml-node-before-import) but with multiple values and changing "|" to ",".

XML for import

```
<safety>|4|8|9|10|11|19|20|22|</safety>
```

XML containing safety IDs and desc

```
<item>
  <ID>1</ID>
  <Description>Alarm</Description>
</item>
<item>
  <ID>2</ID>
  <Description>Airbag</Description>
</item>
<item>
  <ID>3</ID>
  <Description>ABS</Description>
</item>
<item>
```

Comment: For anyone who stumbles upon this question. You can create a custom php function to do this nowadays. See http://www.wpallimport.com/documentation/advanced/execute-php/